# Need to replicate All rows in one tab by All rows in another tab in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hello Excel Vlookup Experts,

I am trying to get a VLOOKUP formula to do the following. Replicate the number of records from the "sample" tab for as many items there are in the "options" tab. I believe this would be some type of distributive action achieved in Excel although I suppose it could be done using coding.

(A) Here is the initial "sample" data set. There are actually 41565 rows in the actual sample set but I have included the first 10 for illustration. 
[image]

(B) Here is the initial "options" data set.

[image]

(C) Here is a representation of what I'm looking for..for the full 41565 x 9 = 374085 records.
[image]

My concern also is that this approach is time consuming even if the formula is corrected to make it distribute correctly. I still need to manually drag down down the formulas manually for 374085 rows and then copy/paste values into another tab each time. I'm hoping there is a better solution either via VBScript or some other method either via Excel or perhaps coding outside of excel such as using JSON. That's an effort for another day.

In the past with Excel I have had some success in replicating smaller datasets where the number of records of in both tabs were the same. So far when it comes to replicating a set of sample records (i.e. 10 records) have used this formula below which allows for repeating 9 times for 90 repetitions of a given Email Address, Zipcode, City, State.

Email Address (begin at Cell B2 on Formulas tab)

```
=IF(ROWS(options!$A$1:$A$2)>COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11),"",INDEX(sample!$B$2:$B$11,CEILING((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11)),1)))
```

ZipCode (begin at Cell C2 on Formulas tab)

```
=IF(ROWS(options!$A$1:$A$2)>COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11),"",INDEX(sample!$C$2:$C$11,CEILING((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11)),1)))
```

City (begin at Cell D2 on Formulas tab)

```
=IF(ROWS(options!$A$1:$A$2)>COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11),"",INDEX(sample!$D$2:$D$11,CEILING((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11)),1)))
```

State (begin at Cell E2 on Formulas tab)

```
=IF(ROWS(options!$A$1:$A$2)>COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11),"",INDEX(sample!$E$2:$E$11,CEILING((ROW()-1)/(COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11)),1)))
```

For the 'Service Type' column, a different repetition is occurring. 10x9x10

When it comes to replicating a set of sample records (i.e. 10 records) I have used this formula below which allows for repeating the range accounting for up to 900 rows (10 rows in sample x 9 rows in options x 10 times need for items in options tab to multiple into sample rows). However, "as-is" it will display #REF! beyond 900 as it does not yet have the needed adjustment to say repeat the process it did for the first 900 again for the next 900 and again for as many rows that exists.

(begin at Cell F2 on Formulas tab)

```
=IF(ROWS(options!$A$1:$A$2)>COUNTA(options!$A$1:$A$9)*COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11),"",INDEX(options!$A$1:$A$9,CEILING((ROW()-1)/COUNTA(sample!A$2:$A$11),1)))
```

Can anyone provide at minimal a fix to the formula so it will work or better a more universal and streamlined approach to solving that work for data sets that will is more flexible in handling both small and large data sets where the 2 data set rows being joined don't have the same number of elements?

Comment: So for each record you want to create 9 rows for each option? i.e. 1 record with 2 options would yield 18 rows? And 3 records with 5 options would yield 135 records?

Comment: Wait. I think I initially explaining this in a confusing way. I was looking at something else earlier that made me believe it would require duplication 9 times but it does not appear to be the case. It's sample rows x number of option rows. I should probably revise the question.

Comment: I think he meant # of recs * # of options, so 3 records with 5 options are becoming 15 new records (see below)

Comment: Correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, I strongly suggest VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRecords()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsExp As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastcell As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lLastOpt As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

' Set Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

' Set Worksheets
    Set wsSource = wb.Sheets("sample")
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("output")
    Set wsExp = wb.Sheets("options")

' Determine # of rows
    Set lastcell = wsSource.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell)
    lLastRow = lastcell.Row

' Copy Header
    wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(1, 1), wsSource.Cells(1, 5)).Copy wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(1, 1), wsDest.Cells(1, 5))
    wsDest.Cells(1, 6) = wsExp.Cells(1, 1)

' Last row in Options
    lLastOpt = 10

' Loop through the rows
    For i = 0 To lLastRow - 2

' copy the record lLastOpt times (or whatever is required) and add the option. To make it more flexible, use another "lastcell" variable
        For j = 2 To lLastOpt
            wsSource.Range(wsSource.Cells(i + 2, 1), wsSource.Cells(i + 2, 5)).Copy wsDest.Range(wsDest.Cells(i * (lLastOpt - 1) + j, 1), wsDest.Cells(i * (lLastOpt - 1) + j, 5))   ' adjust column as necessary
            wsDest.Cells(i * (lLastOpt - 1) + j, 6) = wsExp.Cells(j, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Anything else gets awfully complicated.

Comment: Nice. Except when I copy/paste on the output tab and run it uses "Service" as a heading but then leaves off "Service" and shows blank where Service should be so there is blank between "OTHER" and "NEW_WATER". Can you provide a fix?

Comment: just add as first row in "options" the header "Service Type".

The sub takes all options starting from row 2

Comment: Awesome. Works for the smaller dataset of 10 x 9 but VBA is spinning (Not Responding) for the 41565 rows. Is there a threshold to what it can handle? My system has 8GB RAM and 1 TB HD space here (55% free).

Comment: VBA is rather slow, so for your 41565 x 9 records I would suggest letting the machine work and grab a nice cold beer from the fridge... ;-). My guess is something between 30 and 60 minutes, depending on the power of your CPU. If you want to see where the routine is currently, add a ```Debug.print i``` after the ```For i = ...``` (and make sure that the direct output window is visible)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. Tested twice and took 30min and 55min. Both times the printer show i counter incrementing up to 114 and then froze until final output finished.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, I just posted a [NodeJS/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414513/how-to-maximize-nodejs-performance-when-multiplying-a-json-object-by-an-array-to) alternative approach in another thread to solving my same question with faster execution time than VBA so there is no long wait...although it too has a threshold limit as well but I'm hopeful to discover finding a way to push it's capacity to multiplying n-Millions of records.