# How to maximize NodeJS performance when multiplying a JSON object by an array to create a larger product json larger than 1M records

Tags: javascript, node.js

Below, I am looking for advice on how to handle cross multiplying 2 fields from a json object by all items in an array to create a larger dataset than would be Millions of records. Is there a hard limit to what NodeJS (V8 engine) can handle and how is it quantified?

In my attempt to use a very helpful [VBA in Excel solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391874/need-to-replicate-all-rows-in-one-tab-by-all-rows-in-another-tab-in-excel) provided for my Stackoverflow question to perform multiplication of rows from 2 separate tabs, I ran into a bottleneck issue when dealing with ~42K thousands of rows of data x 9 rows resulting in over 374085 rows generated dynamically by VBA. The VBA in Excel worked but processing was slower than expected (varying from 30min to an hour to complete).

When I turned to NodeJS with the Chrome V8 engine to do this same process. After performing an initial conversion of the csv file to json (sample.json), it performed it within 4 seconds (which includes converting the json to csv file). I will post my code below but keep in mind it is only 41565 x 9 => 374085 record json/csv file.

First install the npm module 'fast-csv'.

**perform_multiplication_of_JSON_with_arrayObject.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
var fileName = "sample.json";
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("" + fileName + "", "utf8");
var sample = JSON.parse(fileContent);

var options = ['SERVICE','NEW_WATER','NEW_COFFEE','NEW_FILTRATION','WEB_SITE','MEDIA_INQUIRY','DONATIONS','RD_INQUIRY','OTHER'];

var newSample = [];

  for(var i = 0;i< sample.length;i++) {
    for (var x= 0;x < options.length;x++) {
        var counter = i*x;
        newSample.push({"id": i, 
                         "Email Address": sample[i]["Email Address"], 
                         "Zipcode": sample[i]["Zipcode"], 
                         "City": sample[i]["City"], 
                         "State": sample[i]["State"], 
                         "Contact Regarding": options[x]});
     }
  }

console.log(newSample);

//write file to a csv
fastcsv.writeToPath("csvoutput/newsample.csv", newSample, {headers: true})
 .on("finish", function(){
     console.log("newsample.csv file writing done!");
});
```

**sample.json** (for brevity i'm including 3 records but it's actually 41565 records)

[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "Email Address": "newyork@ourcompany.com",
        "Zipcode": 501,
        "City": "Holtsville",
        "State": "NY",
        "Contact Regarding": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "Email Address": "newyork@ourcompany.com",
        "Zipcode": 544,
        "City": "Holtsville",
        "State": "NY",
        "Contact Regarding": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "Email Address": "massachussetts@ourcompany.com",
        "Zipcode": 1001,
        "City": "Agawam",
        "State": "MA",
        "Contact Regarding": ""
      }
    ]

If/When I run into a problem with larger data sets needing to perform the same idea, what would be the threshold before I encountered a Javascript Memory Heap Errors? I visited the [Majestic Million website](https://blog.majestic.com/development/majestic-million-csv-daily/) to grab a larger data set and tried experimenting and appropriately changing the code to match the fields in that data set. I quickly saw that using a dataset such as 1M or 500M, I could not attempt the sample type of processor across 9 items without seeing these Javascript Memory Heap Errors.

Can anyone provide a recommendation on how to increase the NodeJS performance for memory? As mentioned, trying to cross 1M records x 9 and 500K records x 9 both give this message which seems to display after about 10-15 seconds of processing. However, when I chopped the majestic million file down at 250K records and retried it as 250K x 9 => 2.2M resulting records the script processed successfully. It would be great to know what to do to get around the JS Memory Heap. Is it solvable with a simple tweak or module?

Security context: 0x0384ce31e6e1 
    1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [000002F7A4D02291] [C:\node-projects\www\lesson_arrays\node_modules@fast-csv\format\build\src\index.js:~42] [pc=0000024872377D81](this=0x02a2dba826f1 ,prev=0x03f9c7e416b9 ,row=0x037e777200c1 )
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 4->2
    3: re...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF61D05ECF5
 2: 00007FF61D0381A6
 3: 00007FF61D038BB0
 4: 00007FF61D2C9AAE
 5: 00007FF61D2C99DF
 6: 00007FF61D807724
 7: 00007FF61D7FDE87
 8: 00007FF61D7FC3FC
 9: 00007FF61D805377
10: 00007FF61D8053F6
11: 00007FF61D3A84B7
12: 00007FF61D44019A
13: 00000248722DC5C1

Comment: You want to use a streaming csv reader/writer. Simply do not attempt to load all 9 million rows in memory at once.

Comment: Alternatively, just use a database. They're built specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already familiar with sql to do the cross joins which are more robust but I'm trying to do it without the database or excel when db isn't available or I don't want to use. This approach has it's advantages in speed up to a certain size without needing to db login. I hadn't thought about csv reader/writer...so doing the processing in smaller batches makes sense.